# How to get cisco incoming call number in C#?

Tags: c#, cisco

How to Get Incoming call number?

What is the any way to get Incoming call number with C#?

For example, to invoke Dial I use this code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

public class FileConverter
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://xx.xx.xx.xx/CGI/Execute HTTP/1.1");
        request.Method = "POST";
        string postData = @"XML=<CiscoIPPhoneExecute><ExecuteItem Priority=""0"" URL=""Dial:1566""/>                                </CiscoIPPhoneExecute>";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=\"UTF-8\"";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
}
```